# Whats the best way to get a Custom Element object for Conditional Elements

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

Using Polymer Dart I often need to get hold of the Polymer-Element object behind one of the child elements.

```
ButtonElement nextButton;

void inserted()
{
  //Get hold of the elements
  nextButton = shadowRoot.query('#nextButton');
  //Do some thing useful with nextButton
}

<template if="{{emailValid}}">
   <button id="nextButton" on-click="nextStep">
</template>
```

This works fine. However if in this case nextButton is underneath a conditional template its not part of the DOM when inserted() is called and is therefore not found. Is there anyway other way to get hold of it?

Otherwise I will have to some how determine when that conditional template is displayed and grab it then.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on what exactly "Do something useful with nextButton" means, but the Polymer-ic way to accomplish this is generally to encapsulate any reusable behavior together with the DOM it operates on. That is, instead of including code to operate on `#nextButton` in the *enclosing* element's `inserted` method, create a new custom element, let's call it `super-button`, and put the relevant code in `super-button`'s `ready` or `inserted` method.

Then, if you find some behavior that really should be outside of `super-button`, follow the same pattern as the `on-click` handler you use above. Have `super-button` fire a [custom event](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#fire) at the appropriate time and then declaratively map a handler to that event:

```
<template if="{{emailValid}}">
   <super-button on-click="nextStep" on-my-special-event="mySpecialEventHandler"></super-button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case do something useful is add a value change handler I added to work around an MDV bug in the current Polymer.dart build which prevents bound attributes updating. So this particular scenario is a bit artificial.

I was really hoping there was some other way of accessing the Xtag object. Although I guess it probably doesn't exist until its element is first displayed.